# JQuery load() of external PHP, images don't work

Tags: php, jquery, external

I hope this question has not been asked before, I have done my best searching.

I have a site with links pointing to php files in subfolders, like this:

index.php/projects/nameofproject/project.php

In the case of no javascript the user will simply be redirected to the project.php and will be able to see the content.

The project.php file displays the content of two txt files and also all images present in the nameofproject folder, like so (I realize that the handling of variables might not be great but I'm quite new at this):

```
<?php
    $imagesFile = glob("*.jpg");
    $headingFile = "heading.txt";
    $ph = fopen($headingFile, 'r');
    $heading = fread($ph, filesize($headingFile));
    fclose($ph);
    $infoFile = "info.txt";
    $ih = fopen($infoFile, 'r');
    $info = fread($ih, filesize($infoFile));
    fclose($ih);

    echo '
        <h2>'.$heading.'</h2>
        <p>'.$info.'</p>
    ';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($imagesFile); $i++)
    {
        $imageName = $imagesFile[$i];
        echo '
            <img src="'.$imageName.'">
        ';
    }
?>
```

This works so far but when I try to load the project.php in a div on the index.php page the images show up as broken links. The code relating to the text files work.

JQuery code (I will be more specific later, not targeting all links):

```
$("a").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault()
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".details").empty();
    $(".details").load(href);
});
```

The problem seems to be that the php file (project.php) tries to load the images as if they are in the same folder as that file, which works when that is the case (no javascript) but not when I use JQuery to load() project.php on index.php

How can i make the images work when I load the project.php on the index.php page?

Comment: Use absolute URLs with your images, or set a basepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set absolute file paths to stop the browser reading them from where they have been opened. 
The easiest way would be to add `/` which will refer to the root of your file system. This will still depend on how you're set up.

So update `$imagesFile = glob("*.jpg");` with where the images are store:

```
  $imagesFile = glob("/pathtoimages/*.jpg");
```

Comment: Since the directory one step up from the images can vary i tried this:
`$projectName = "/projects/" . basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) . "/";`

and

`echo ' <img src="'.$projectName.''.$imageName.'">`

But this doesn't work even though when I look at the result the path looks to be correct.

Comment: :O madness :) Can you navigate to the image by typing the url manually into the browser? If so, paste that here along with what is being output with your `php`

Comment: I had to remove the first "/" in the projectName variable! Thanks for your answer.